# PowerShell script not working on server

Tags: asp.net, powershell

I have a simple PowerShell script in which I try to write some log data.
The script that's not working:

```
Add-Content -Path C:\temp\logg.txt -Value $file.FullName
```

This line I placed in the middle of the script and I never get any text in the logg.txt. The Script executes fine except this, it compiles some files to a zip file.
This is on a Windows server.

If I, however, run the same script on my local machine, Win7, it does work!?

So I think it must be something with the server but I can't figure it out. Am using `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` when I run the script.

EDIT: more info.

The script is called from an ASP.NET webpage:

```vb
Process.Start("Powershell.exe", "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command ""& {" & destinationFolderRoot.Replace("\\", "\") & "\scriptParameters.ps1}""")
```

BaseZipScript:

```bsh
function New-Zip
{
    param([string]$zipfilename)
    Set-Content $zipfilename ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))
    (dir $zipfilename).IsReadOnly = $false
}

function Add-Zip
{
    param([string]$zipfilename)

    if(-not (Test-Path($zipfilename)))
    {
        Set-Content $zipfilename ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))
        (dir $zipfilename).IsReadOnly = $false
    }

    $shellApplication = New-Object -COM Shell.Application
    $zipPackage = $shellApplication.NameSpace($zipfilename)

    foreach($file in $input) 
    { 
        $zipPackage.CopyHere($file.FullName)
        Add-Content -Path "C:\temp\logg.txt" -Value $file.FullName
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 750
    }
}
```

scriptParameters1:

```bsh
. "C:\temp\multiDownload\baseZipScript.ps1"

New-Zip c:\temp\multiDownload\user379\2016-09-15_14.39\files_2016-09-15_14.39.zip
dir c:\temp\multiDownload\user379\2016-09-15_14.39\tempCopy\*.* -Recurse |
    Add-Zip c:\temp\multiDownload\user379\2016-09-15_14.39\files_2016-09-15_14.39.zip
Start-sleep -milliseconds 250

exit
```

As I said earlier the script works on local machine and also on the server, e.g. the files are being zipped, except that on the server nothing is logged in logg.txt.

Though the logg.txt works and exists on the server because the webpage also log some info there and that is being written.

Update:
As the comments guessed it was as simple as write access to the file. Though, it is kind of wierd because all files are created from the webservice if they doesn't exists? Any how, it works now. Thx! : )

Comment: Could it be that `$file` is not a `FileInfo` instance on your server but something else? And that the file gets an empty line appended instead of nothing happening?

Comment: How are you calling the script? How is `$file` defined? I don't think we can answer this without more information.

Comment: added some code as requested

Comment: Does the web server process have write access to `C:\temp`?

Comment: I'd guees so since it can create the folder c:\temp\multiDownload and create zip files in that folder and I've haven't granted any permissions to that folder, but I'll check it out.

Comment: Are you running this via full IIS? If so, what credentials are you using on the app pool?

Comment: Sry for late answer but Ansgar you were correct so if you'd just post yoiut comment as an answer i'll mark it  as the correct answer.